# How to toggle VS2022 "Exclude From Build" with a shortkey or toolbar button?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I have to often toggle "Exclude From Build" option for different files in VS2022 and it takes too much time to get to project properties and toggle the option there.

Is there a way to assign this to short-key or at least toolbar button?

Comment: It is not usual to do this action often. If you are making several builds of the same project then you could have different project configurations (Release - X, Release - Y).

Comment: @Dialecticus, I use a project to test some language features or algorithms before introducing to a large project. So, I add file, work on it, then exclude from build, add another file, etc. When I need to get back to this "test" I just include it back to build and compile. This happens dozens times a day. My savings are on creating and configuring many projects on this. What approach for that would you recommend?

Comment: You could also use macros. Every source is guarded with one `#ifdef`, and you also have one common header file #included by all those other sources with bunch of `#define` in it. Then you just edit that one common header.

Comment: I assume you work with C++ projects. If you work with C# then it's `#if` instead of `#ifdef`, and macros are defined in one edit box in project properties.

Comment: But in C# project you can introduce one TestConfiguration class that would just hold a bunch of `public const bool` values. And use those to decide what features should run.